# odoo, how to create a correct xpath expression

Tags: xpath, odoo-14

I'm doing the [odoo getting started tutorial](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/13_inheritance.html). And I need to create a xpath expression. I need to inherit the base.view_users_form view and add page to display a list of properties.
This page should go after the preferences page, so I created this expresssion.

```
<record id="inherited_res_user_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.users.extended.form</field>
    <field name="model">res.users</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//page[@name='preferences']" position="after">
            <field name="property_ids"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

and the error:

```
Element '<xpath expr="//page[@name='preferences']">' cannot be located in parent view
```

So I know my expression is incorrect, but I dont know what it should be.

I also don't know how I can find out. I [read](https://learnopenerp.blogspot.com/2018/01/inheritance-in-models-and-views.html) a bit about how it works, and I think I understand sufficiently. But I think I need to see the source code of base.view_users_form to find how they name their elements so that I can properly use xpath. But I can't find the source code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully in the [view_users_form](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/views/res_users_views.xml#L236) code, you will see that the page is named `references` and not `preferences`.

Try the following XPath:

```
<xpath expr="//page[@name='references']" position="after">
    <page string="Properties" name="property_ids">
        <field name="property_ids"/>
    </page>
</xpath>
```

Comment: It says in the tutorial that an extension view references its parent using the inherited_id field. I knew that the inherited_id field had to be "base.view_users_form", so I assumed that the parent would have the field `<field name="name">base.view_users_form</field>`.  Do you know why this not the case?

Comment: The `inherit_id` should be the parent view `id` (attribute set on the record tag) and in your example above you used the parent view [external identifier](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/glossary.html#term-external-identifier) (`module_name.view_id`) which allows referring to the record without having to know its in-database identifier